# emacs programming assembly . Multiple comment lines column !=0

Tags: emacs, programming-languages, comments, line

Hi I am a working about AT&T assembly x86 architecture programming and I need emacs editor with assembly functions. So, I am editing with assembly editing mode asm-mode and [gas-mode](http://www.hczim.de/software/gas-mode.html).

I have a question about MULTIPLE COMMENTS LINES funcionality. When I select a region like buffer full with C-x h and automatic format with C-M \ if the multiple lines comments are at column 0 there is no problem, the result is OK.
But if the block of multiple comments (# symbol) lines are at comments column field, par example column 34

```
_start:               
    movl (%ebp), eax  # comment line 0
                      # comment line 1
                      # comment line 2
```

the process of format full-buffer automation C_M \ put the comments line at star of the line in column 0.

What can I do, please, if i want comments blocks begin at comment column field ? There is some elisp function for beautyfing differentes types of comments o differents comments-char symbol, par example # for field comment column number and ##  for column 0?

Thanks in advance 
Candido

Answer (score 2):

After some lectures I have a solution to the problem of comment levels. There is no user guide about asm programming mode, but reading emacs manual and some intuition with asm-mode.el elisp language, I have some conclusions:

- Use asm mode and not gas mode.
- Customize asm comment char to # symbol.
- Set the fill prefix with the `C-x .` command (`set-fill-prefix`).
- Use 4 comment levels:

  `# -> end line comment`

  `## -> operand column comment`

  `### -> begin line comment`

  `/*   */ -> multiple line comments`
- C-M\ re-indenting region
- M-; -> re-indenting comment line